# External import url's in main.scss file not getting bundled when deployed with ng build --prod

Tags: css, angular

I have recently migrated an angular seed application to angular 6 cli. I have an external import in my main.scss file like this:
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400');

And I have included the styles inside my angular.json file:

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/redmond/theme.css" ,
    "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
    "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
    "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
    "src/main.scss"
],
```

However, after an ng build --prod , when I check in the prod environment the css is not getting bundled . I made sure of this by checking the Network tab in my debugger. In my localhost , everything works perfectly fine.
However inside the dist folder, I have a "styles..bundle.css" file with all my main.scss styles in it excluding the ones from the external import url.
Any ideas where to start?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://update.angular.io/

Comment: You are not required to import main.scss files. only third party node modules css/scss files are required to import.

Comment: No, this does not have anything specific to css or fonts related changes.

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya So how does main.scss get bundled in the final index.html file in dist folder during build if we don't specify it in angular.json file?

Comment: Why can't you hit the HTTP URL in browser and paste the content in style.css file

Comment: Would suggest import the main.scss file in the app.component.scss file

Comment: Hitting the url and copying the contents doesn't work. It doesn't get bundled on page load.

Comment: This worked after I removed all the styles from angular.json except main.scss and added them in main.scss!!